# Static methods and the service locator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I have a static helper method in my ASP.NET MVC application. Here is some sample code that demonstrates the issue (the actual code is a bit more complex). Please focus on the pattern. The actual code does not interact with a database.

The code below is abstracted to allow for unit testing. The issue I have is getting the concrete implementation for IDatabaseManager. Is using a service locator bad? Any recommendations on good pratices? I have read that service locators are the anti-pattern. Please advise. All other places in code are using dependency injection (the problem here is obviously the static DataWriter method).

```
public static class DataWriter {
    public static void WriteDate() {
        var datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        //Is this service locator a bad pattern?
        var databaseManager = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IDatabaseManager>();
        var dataRepository = new DataRepository(databaseManager);

        dataRepository.Write(datetime);
    }
}

public class DatabaseManager : IDatabaseManager {
    public void Write(string s) {
        //Write to database 
    }
    //Other methods
    ...
    ...
}

public interface IDatabaseManager {
    void Write(string s);
    //Other signatures
    ...
    ...
}

public class DataRepository : IDataRepository {
    private IDatabaseManager _databaseManager;
    public DataRepository(IDatabaseManager databaseManager) {
        _databaseManager = databaseManager;
    }

    public void Write(string data) {
        _databaseManager.Write(data);   
    }   
}

public interface IDataRepository {
    void Write(string data);
}
```

Editing as per the recommendation of Alex.
Editing again to remove the information about cshtml (as that is not the focus of the question)

Comment: *Writing* to database from CSHTML so controversial that I would not worry about using service locator in addition to it. Side note: you may want to restate your question (maybe you mean "should I use Service locator", because clearly you sample does use it ).

Comment: The question is not about writing to the database. The actual code does not write or interact with the database. This is pseudo code to demonstrate the issue. Again, my question is I am using a service locator but should I be using it in the first place. I am asking for recommendations on why this is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read that service locators are the anti-pattern

Maybe not 100%, but they should be discouraged. [Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann) explains that [Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

I think you should be looking towards [Dependency Injection](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html).

The problem you face is that dependency resolution is inherently difficult with static methods.

I would suggest that you look into implementing non-static methods and dependency injection from elsewhere in your application. As **Alexei** pointed out, calling things from a **View** isn't ideal.

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Dependency Injection](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks like this is the key. I should avoid static methods and using dependency injection from elsewhere.